# C++ MongoDB Client as a class member

Tags: c++, mongodb, class, client, member

I'm programming a server side C++ music application. I'm stuck with the Database part, I choose MongoDB to go with and I'm not the boss in C++.

I made a Database class which stores the MongoDB unique instance and I would like to create multiple MongoDB clients on the fly like this

```
this->setDatabaseURI(&this->uri, "mongodb://localhost:27017");

mongocxx::client *cli1 = this->createNewClient();

mongocxx::client *cli2 = this->createNewClient();

mongocxx::client *cli3 = this->createNewClient();

auto db1 = cli1["myAppDB"];
auto db2 = cli2["myAppDB"];
auto db3 = cli3["myAppDB"];
```

compiler says:

```
PATH/Database.cpp:31:20: error: array subscript is not an integer
auto db1 = cli1["myAppDB"];
               ^~~~~~~~~~
PATH/Database.cpp:32:20: error: array subscript is not an integer
auto db2 = cli2["myAppDB"];
               ^~~~~~~~~~
PATH/Database.cpp:33:20: error: array subscript is not an integer
auto db3 = cli3["myAppDB"];
               ^~~~~~~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

The goal was to create clients on the fly using pointers and call the createNewClient() function when a new client is needed.

```
mongocxx::client *Database::createNewClient()
{
  mongocxx::client *cli = new mongocxx::client();
  return (cli);
}
```

if I do like this it works:

```
mongocxx::client conn;
auto db = conn["myAppDB"];
```

I don't understand why? What "[]" are in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to call [] operator on the pointer, which obviously does not work. You should dereference pointer and call it on the object instance instead:

```
auto d = (*cli1)["myAppDB"];
```

Comment: Is [] the operator new as described here ?http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: no, in your case it's overloaded `operator [](const std::string?)` of the `mongocxx::client` class.

Comment: Doing with `auto d = (*cli1)["myAppDB"];` gives this error at runtime : `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type mongocxx::v_noabi::logic_error: invalid use of default constructed or moved-from mongocxx::client object`

Comment: Construct your client properly. You have to pass connection string, while you create a "default constructed client", which is clearly described in [MongoDB docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.0.1/classmongocxx_1_1client.html)

Comment: new mongocxx::client("CONNECTION_STRING_HERE");

Comment: it works if I construct the client with the URI at the same time. Nice :)